# Selecionar o dataframe com maior número de linhas em uma lista R

Tags: r

Olá,

Estou desenhando um loop e em um determinado momento preciso selecionar o dataframe com maior número de linhas dentro de uma lista.

Exemplo:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:15)
df2 <- data.frame(b = 1:35)
df3 <- data.frame(c = 1:105)
lista <- list(df1, df2, df3)

# resultado esperado lista[[3]]
```

De alguma forma, eu queria que eu pudesse dizer "retorne-me o elemento da lista com maior nrow() .

Agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: A outra possibilidade é calcular número de linhas no interior do loop. Algo assim: fora do loop: vec <- numeric(). Dentro do loop: vec[i] <- nrow(df1); list(df1, df2, df3)[[which.max(vec)]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consegui encontrar uma resposta que não é ideal mas serve para os meus propósitos.

```
#contando o número de linhas de cada dfs:
cnt <- sapply(lista, nrow)
# Agora atribuindo a um DF final:
df_final <- data.frame(lista[which.max(cnt)])
```

Comment: Nota: `lista[[which.max(cnt)]]` é suficiente. Usa `'[['` em vez de `'['` para extrair o *elemento* da lista dado por `which.max`, que é o df pretendido. A outra forma extrai uma *sub-lista* e é por isso que é necessário usar `data.frame()` depois.